# getMove cannot be resolved to a variable, thought I declared that variable but maybe others eyes can see it

Tags: java, variables

I am trying to create a Rock, Paper, Scissors game using a tester file and a class file for a class, unfortunately, when I got to this point I ran into the error that return getMove(); will not function properly and I can't seem to fix it. Any help is appreciated and any recommendations to improve the code while keeping it to basic Java would also be appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class startGame {
    public String ROCK;
    public String PAPER;
    public String SCISSORS;
    private enum Move { 
        ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS
    }

    private class playerOne {

        private Scanner inputScanner;
        public playerOne () {
        inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);}

    public Move getMove(String ROCK, String PAPER, String SCISSORS) {
        //What does player One wish to play
        System.out.println("Player One: Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");


        //get the user input
        String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
        char firstLetter = userInput.charAt(0);
        if (firstLetter == 'R' || firstLetter == 'P' ||  firstLetter == 'S') {
            //Users input is valid:
            switch (firstLetter) {
            case 'R':
                return Move.ROCK;
            case 'P':
                return Move.PAPER;
            case 'S':
                return Move.SCISSORS;
            }
        }
        return getMove(ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS);


        {
        return startGame.getMove;
    }
}
    private Scanner inputScannerTwo;
 private class playerTwo {
     public Move getMove() {
        //What does player One wish to play
            System.out.println("Player Two: Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");

            inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            //get the user input
            String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
            userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
            char firstLetter = userInput.charAt(0);
            if (firstLetter == 'R' || firstLetter == 'P' ||  firstLetter == 'S') {
                //Users input is valid:
                switch (firstLetter) {
                case 'R':
                    return Move.ROCK;
                case 'P':
                    return Move.PAPER;
                case 'S':
                    return Move.SCISSORS;
         return startGame.getMove;
     }
 }

     }
 }
}
}
```

-------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------------------
So I added

```
public static Move getMove() {
return null;
}
```

This seemed to fix all the errors contained in Eclipse.  However, I still cannot get it to run in my tester method.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors? (Yes/No)");
    String gameStart = in.nextLine();
    if(gameStart.equals("Yes")) {

         //start game goes here
     new startGame();

    }else {
        System.out.println("Then why the hell are you here?");
    }
```

This is how I tried to invoke it in my main method, everything else in the main method works except for this portion above.

Comment: What is this doing: `startGame.getMove;`?

Comment: sorry should be startGame.getMove(); and it is supposed to be restarting the getMove to ask again if the player enters something different from Rock, Paper, or Scissors.

Comment: I don't know why you are using this line:  return startGame.getMove;    But if you want to use it really you need to modify it to  return startGame.getMove();

Comment: And what do you thing this does: `public Move getMove(String ROCK, String PAPER, String SCISSORS)`?

Comment: create the method, and/or constructor?

Comment: What do you mean by "create", what do you mean by "and/or constructor"?

Comment: shouldn't that build a class or a constructor, in this case it should be a class but I have a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the code, you're getting the lowercase character as input and comparing it with the uppercase characters. Use following code to get the upper case input

```
String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: It still has getMove(); is undefined for startGame, and I don't really know how to get it defined...